# In attemp to assign known value to container.scrollLeft, it is getting assigned an unknown value

Tags: javascript

Following are the HTML and Javascript codes of my project. You can view them [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Paras_Mahajan/ar15o08y/3/) along with CSS.

I have created 8 `div`s 150px wide which lie horizontally in a row flexbox of 600px width. Out of 8, only 4 are visible at a time and the rest can be viewed by scrolling using the side buttons provided. I have used `requestAnimationFrame` to produce a scrolling effect(600px per scroll).

In my Javascript code I have commented some lines as `COMMENTED`. Those are of concern. Their behaviour can be seen in console as the code runs. `nu_value - prev_value` computes to some value let say 6 so 6 will be logged in the console. After that 6 should be assigned to `container.scrollLeft` but it is not happening as the next line of code logs its value to be different than 6. The result of this behaviour is that content doesn't scroll to the right completely(<600px) when clicking the right side button.

The same problem lies with scrolling left. Why is this happening?

```
<body>
    <button id="button_left"> < </button>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="sub1" class="sub">1</div>
        <div id="sub2" class="sub">2</div>
        <div id="sub3" class="sub">3</div>
        <div id="sub4" class="sub">4</div>
        <div id="sub5" class="sub">5</div>
        <div id="sub6" class="sub">6</div>
        <div id="sub7" class="sub">7</div>
        <div id="sub8" class="sub">8</div>
    </div>
    <button id="button_right"> > </button>
</body>
```

---

```
let container = document.querySelector("#container");
let button_left = document.querySelector('#button_left');
let button_right = document.querySelector('#button_right');

button_left.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(container.scrollLeft > 0){
        let start, elapsed, progress, prev_value = 0, nu_value, stop = 0;
        requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
        function scroll(){
            if(start === undefined)
            start = new Date().getTime();
            elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
            if(stop == 0){
                console.log(elapsed);
                progress = Math.round((elapsed/900).toFixed(2) * 600); // 900 is time to scroll in ms
                nu_value = Math.min(progress, 600);
                if(nu_value == 600)
                stop = 1;
                console.log(`difference = ${nu_value - prev_value}`);  //COMMENTED
                container.scrollLeft -= nu_value - prev_value;          //COMMENTED
                console.log(`scrollLeft = ${container.scrollLeft}`);   //COMMENTED   
                prev_value = nu_value;
                requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
            }
        }
    }
});
button_right.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(container.scrollLeft >= 0){
        let start, elapsed, progress, prev_value = 0, nu_value, stop = 0;
        requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
        function scroll(){
            if(start === undefined)
            start = new Date().getTime();
            elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
            if(stop == 0){
                console.log(elapsed);
                progress = Math.round((elapsed/900).toFixed(2) * 600); // 900 is time to scroll in ms
                nu_value = Math.min(progress, 600);
                if(nu_value == 600)
                stop = 1;
                console.log(`difference = ${nu_value - prev_value}`);  //COMMENTED
                container.scrollLeft += nu_value - prev_value;          //COMMENTED
                console.log(`scrollLeft = ${container.scrollLeft}`);   //COMMENTED   
                prev_value = nu_value;
                requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do you get the `900` from?

Comment: I want the scroll to take 900ms.

Comment: Puh, complex. I managed to get the right scroll position to element 5. Just by repeating. How about the route to take CSS for the `transition`?

Comment: But I want to know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: It is advanced. But `requestAnimationFrame()` is probably dependent on every bit the `CPU`has to calculate. 

Comment: Please try to explain the code. In my imagination the scroller has to stop at the 4. element. How do you code that?  Please fiddle.

Comment: In the fiddle when you click on the right button it should scroll the content right by 600px i.e. upto end of 8 element but it is not so. why?

Comment: The end of the 8. element is -- not -- at 600px. It is at 8*150 = 1200px. ;)

Comment: I mean to say it will scroll 600px so that next 600px content should be visible completely and thus 8th element should be completely in the view but it is not happeing so.

Comment: first line of the 3 commented lines prints the value of subtraction of two variables. Then in second line I store that value into container.scrollLeft. Then in third line I print the value of container.scrollLeft but to my surprise it doesn't prints the same value that it stored.

Comment: For me it works: `scrollLeft = 456"
"difference = 6"
"scrollLeft = 462"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the case where elapsed > 900.  Envision the case where `elapsed` was 899 and took more than 1ms before the next invocation of `scroll`.

```
nu_value = Math.round((Math.min(elapsed,900)/900).toFixed(2) * 600);
         
console.log(`difference = ${nu_value - prev_value}`);  //COMMENTED
            
container.scrollLeft += nu_value - prev_value;         //COMMENTED
            
console.log(`scrollLeft = ${container.scrollLeft}`);   //COMMENTED
prev_value = nu_value;
if (elapsed < 900) {                
    requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work even then. Moreover I am astonished to see the result of the excecution of those 3 commented lines. First commented line logs the value of `nu_value - prev_value`. Second commented line stores the logged value into `container.scrollLeft`. Third line logs the value of `container.scrollLeft` and to my surprise the logged value is different from what it stored. How is this happening

Comment: Rather than calculating your next movement from your last movement, try calculating your position as a treen between 2 fixed values